# Welcomepage is missing from Quicklauch

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm using a publishing web. I have two pages. The navigation is set to show pages.
It shows two menu items, for each page one item.

The problem:
When setting publishing page 1 as the welcomepage, this page is removed from the quicklaunch navigation.

Probable cause:
The PortalSitemap providers filters the welcomepages from quicklaunch. Probably because the web has the same url as the welcomepage?

Any thoughts about this and how to fix this by configuring the provider?
At this moment I added a (external) node...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add page to navigation directly.
Site Settings => Navigation

Comment: Adding that page through the UI does work. However that page-node isn't completelty the same as the other pages. So I still find this very strange, but for now I fixed it by adding a external node to the navigation collection.

Answer (score -1):

you can use a little trick.
This happens because sharepoint removes the welcome page from the quicklaunch. But if you set the welcomepage with a different URL its appears.
for Ex: if you want the page "XPTO.aspx" to be your welcomepage, set it as "XPTO.aspx?".
this way the page will be set as welcomepage, and it will appear on quick launch .
this happens beacul sharepoint thinks that "xpto.aspx" and "xpto.aspx?" ate 2 different pages, but they are not.